# Triggering Angular2 change detection manually with ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using angular4 , ngrx/store and PeerJS.
I have a service with code to handle connection open event and data receive from other peers. the part of data connection and p2p working.

```
    let conn = peer.connect(remoteId, {reliable: true});
    conn.on('data', (data) => {
        this.store.dispatch(addBlock(data )); //this working !
    });
```

At app component I've subscribed to the store

```
    this.block$ = this.store.select("blockchain") as Observable<Block[]>;

    this.blocks$.subscribe((blockchain:Block[]) => {

        this.lastblock = blockchain[blockchain.length - 1];
        console.log(this.lastblock); // this working ! 
    });
```

At the app template a simple bind to blocks$

```
<div>{{ blocks$ | async }}</div>
```

The problem is that the dom is not updating, It only updates if other operation happens to trigger change detection, such as, focus in out of input, setInterval and so on... so I think the root problem is that the store was updated inside an event that is not recognized in the angular zone.

What is the correct way to solve it?

I've tried to inject changeDetection ref to service and call "this.ref.detectChanges()" but provider is not available in the service.

I've tried to surround the "this.store.dispatch(addBlock(data ));" with setTimeout , not working.

I use default ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: Why not to write the provider?

Comment: In service you can use setTimeout.  it is supported by zone

Comment: Don't understand your Q

Comment: do you use a custom changeDectionStrategy ? (onPush ?)
As you've observables it's not a dumb component and therefore you shouldn't use onPush

Comment: I use default strategy

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you find a solution for it?

Comment: I've left the project :)